# How can I select specific columns when computing average colMeans in a list of matrices?

Tags: r, list, matrix, sapply

I have a list `lst.mx` containing similar matrices.

```
lst.mx <- lapply(1:10, function(X, r = 20) {
  d = matrix(NA, nrow = r, ncol = 4, dimnames = list(NULL, c("fee", "fi", "fo", "fum")))
  d[, 1] = rbinom(r, 1, .375)
  d[, 2] = .42 * rnorm(r, 0, 6)
  d[, 3] = rbinom(r, 11, c(1:11)/11)
  d[, 4] = rbinom(r, 1, .3)
  d
})
```

When I want the mean of specific columns in one matrix I use e. g. `colMeans(lst.mx[[1]][, 2:3])`.

Now since `round(rowMeans(sapply(lst.mx[, 2:3], colMeans)), 3)` throws an `Error in lst.mx[, 2:3] : incorrect number of dimensions` and curiously `dim(lst.mx)` giving `NULL` –

How can I select specific columns in `sapply()` to compute their average means in the whole list?

*Note:* `round(rowMeans(sapply(lst.mx, colMeans)), 3)` is working already fine.

***Edit:*** Okay with @akruns solution I accomplished it with `rowMeans(sapply(lst.mx, function(x) colMeans(x[, 2:3])))`

Forgot to say, I now want to condition on a specific column. I tried it intuitively with `sapply(lst.mx, function(x) colMeans(x[, 2:3][x[, 1] == 0]))` which gives this guy again: `Error in colMeans(x[, 2:3][x[, 1] == 0]) : 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions`.

Actually I want this (probably there's a package which I'm not aware of?):

```
# average colMeans of list conditioned on column one
# fee          fi          fo 
#   0  ?.????????  ?.????????   
#   1  ?.????????  ?.????????
```

Comment: Use an anonymous call `lapply(lst.mx, function(x) colMeans(x[,2:3]))`

Comment: `rowMeans(sapply(lst.mx, function(x) colMeans(x[, 2:3])))` - thanks!

Comment: Ok, and how to condition `sapply(lst.mx, function(x) colMeans(x[, 2:3][x[, 1] == 0]))` correctly? (means only for values which first column = 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just specifying wrong your subset.
Try this:

```
lapply(lst.mx, function(x) colMeans(x[x[,1] == 0,][,2:3]))
```

Note: that first I subset the column == 1 with rows == 0 and then I extract the columns 2 and 3, and finally apply colMeans.